# Using google endpoints with sql

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm still new to GAE, and I would like to have more wisdom about couple of things.
I searched in documentation, but I think I'm just too stupid to understand some things from documentation.

1. How can I combine Google Cloud SQL with endpoints? Is there such possibility?
2. How can I use endpoints to upload videos to google platform?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be able to use anything you can do on a non cloud endpoints api to cloud endpoints like google cloud sql. But since it's on preview you might encounter bugs/changes when it goes out of preview. You should create a Cloud SQL tests models on regular app engine app then try to use it on cloud endpoints, so you can minimize debugging for errors.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/

1. You will need to use a blobstore api:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

on your endpoints have a method that creates the upload url and use that to upload from your app then on the uploadHandler it will trigger once the whole file has been uploaded, process your blobInfo key store it appropriately.